# React web application injected texts virus

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, code-injection, virus

I have built a react web application, and somehow the hardcoded texts get replaced in about 30% of the times to "rude" ones. It seems like a virus, I went through the dependencies there all seems fine. I will also add it here. The server side has only 1 AWS lambda that stores data to mongodb

```
 "dependencies": {
"@vimeo/player": "^2.6.4",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"hex-rgb": "^3.0.0",
"js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
"react": "^16.6.0",
"react-dom": "^16.6.0",
"react-ga": "^2.5.3",
"react-pose": "^3.4.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.0.4"
},
```

Is there any idea to start check? Ever happened to anyone?
If there is any information I can add that might help, please tell me and I will
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you accessing the app behind HTTPS? Is possible that the code is injected during the transport.

Comment: @LucaFabbri yes, but anyways the texts are hardcoded in the client side

Comment: That doesn't matter, a malicious ISP for example can modifiy a JS file sent to the client. However this is not possible behind SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 12 hours of research have passed and here are the conclusions: Google translate has recognized my site as a wrong language and translated it totally wrong. It changed my whole site texts. I am happy it is behind me, I didn't know what to think about. Thanks!